# github get users merged lines of code from a specific date range

Tags: github, pygithub

I have been searching Github documentation well as pygithub documentation as well on how I could get the  stats for each users committed and merged lines of code into the master branch from a specific date. So far the best i could find is under contributions it list out a users committed lines of codes however this gives the stats for the life of the project but i need to filter this by a specific date. Is there anyway to do this appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can pretty easily retrieve a list of the commits from a specific user and in  agiven date range using the pygithub Repository [get_commits](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub/blob/4fb1d23f4def91a45eed4e1b3d567068ccee040b/github/Repository.py#L1680) method. You can see from the method signature below that you can filter by the hash, path, date range, and author.

```py
def get_commits(
        self,
        sha=github.GithubObject.NotSet,
        path=github.GithubObject.NotSet,
        since=github.GithubObject.NotSet,
        until=github.GithubObject.NotSet,
        author=github.GithubObject.NotSet,
    )
```